# Querying from a self made database class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, scope, anonymous-function

thanks for the attention, i am trapped in a code, i am not a really great javascript developer and i am experiencing a difficult creating a Database class, my problem is the scope of the methods im trying to user and encapsulate a postgre connection inside a class:

```
Connector = new require('./connector.js').Connector
PGClient = new require('pg').Client

exports.Database =
  class Database
    constructor:(@connector)->
      @connector = Connector if not @connector
      @client = new PGClient( @connector.connection_string );
      @client.connect()

    close: ->
      @client.end()

    query: (sql) ->
      @client.connect (err) ->
        @client.query 'SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', (err, result) ->
            return result.rows[0].theTime
            #output: Tue Jan 15 2013 19:12:47 GMT-600 (CST)
```

Inside the query method i made a connection and then inside the connect callback i want to use a query using the @client object, i want to call the close method before the return statement to, but in this way, inside the callbacks i dont have access to the object scope.

Is there a way to do that?

code in javascript

```
(function() {
  var Connector, Database, PGClient;

  Connector = new require('./connector.js').Connector;

  PGClient = new require('pg').Client;

  exports.Database = Database = (function() {
    function Database(connector) {
      this.connector = connector;
      if (!this.connector) {
        this.connector = Connector;
      }
      this.client = new PGClient(this.connector.connection_string);
      console.log(this.client);
      this.client.connect();
    }

    Database.prototype.close = function() {
      return this.client.end();
    };

    Database.prototype.query = function(sql) {
      return this.client.connect(function(err) {
        return this.client.query('SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', function(err, result) {
          return result.rows[0].theTime;
        });
      });
    };

    return Database;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: This doesn't look much like Javascript to me.

Comment: its coffeescript but the question is related to javascript, i will post the javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with anything, you need to make a copy before calling `@client.connect()`:

```
query: (sql) ->
  client = @client
  @client.connect (err) ->
    @client.query 'SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', (err, result) ->
        client.close()
        return result.rows[0].theTime
```

In JavaScript:

```
Database.prototype.query = function(sql) {
    var client = this.client;

    return this.client.connect(function(err) {
      return this.client.query('SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', function(err, result) {
        client.close();
        return result.rows[0].theTime;
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the prototype method using scope resolution operator: Database::close();

The equivalent CoffeeScript would be:

```
Connector = new require('./connector.js').Connector
PGClient = new require('pg').Client

exports.Database =
  class Database
    constructor:(@connector)->
      @connector = Connector if not @connector
      @client = new PGClient( @connector.connection_string );
      @client.connect()

    close: ->
      @client.end()

    query: (sql) ->
      @client.connect (err) ->
        @client.query 'SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', (err, result) ->
          Database::close()
          result.rows[0].theTime
```

Comment: Now you've turned it into a singleton.